# Disable Fuzziness in Elasticsearch MatchQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Our team wants to query a referenceId in our Elasticsearch indices. We want to find the hit with referenceId that exactly matches our input.

We can't use TermQuery as this ID is stored as text. So we ended up using MatchQuery.

Here's the code for our ElasticSearchHelper:

```
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
                                                      .query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(key, val).fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO))
                                                      .timeout(TIMEOUT_SECONDS);
    
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest().indices(index).source(searchSourceBuilder);
    return restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
```

Although we have set Fuzziness to zero, we are still getting Fuzzy hits:

Here's the search query: referenceId: 106-0638778-542266

And Here are the search hits:

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": 29.930355,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "XXX_V1",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "21-9689252-9991524",
                "_score": 29.930355,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "21-9689252-9991524",
                    "referenceId": "106-0638778-5422664",
            },
            {
                "_index": "XXX_V1",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "21-3424596-5516719",
                "_score": 19.949657,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "P21-3424596-5516719",
                    "referenceId": "106-0638778-5422661",
             },
             {...}
}]
```

Note that all these hits has different referenceId than 106-0638778-542266

I just want to know how should I disable Fuzziness and only get hit with exact match? I would really appreciate help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A standard tokenizer will break the id into numeric types as follows

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "106",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "0638778",
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "54226",
      "start_offset" : 12,
      "end_offset" : 17,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Match query on numeric types behaves differently.
I would suggest using match phrase query instead.